# How to align Center Vertically the Items in the Row in Android Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've got a Row and 2 Composables  within it (an IconButton and a searchbar) and setting `verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically` but as you see in the following image the button and searchBar wont stand in same height[image]

[image]

and the code block

```
Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(4.dp)
            .height(65.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        SearchBar(
            query = text,
            onQueryChange = { text = it },
            onSearch = { active = false },
            active = active,
            onActiveChange = { active = it },
            placeholder = { Text(text = "Search") },
            leadingIcon = { Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Search, contentDescription = "") },
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(5.dp)
                .weight(weight = 1f, fill = true)

        ) {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
            ) {
                items(4) { idx ->
                    val resultText = "Suggestion $idx"
                    ListItem(
                        headlineContent = { Text(resultText) },
                        supportingContent = { Text("Additional info") },
                        leadingContent = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Star, contentDescription = null) },
                        modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                            text = resultText
                            active = false
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }


        if (!active) {
            IconButton(
                onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(5.dp)
                    .size(55.dp)
                    .background(Color.Cyan)
            ) {
                AsyncImage(
                    model = "",
                    contentDescription = "profile picture",
                    error = rememberVectorPainter(image = Icons.Default.Person)

                )
            }
        }


    }
```

I tried to put items in the box but result was same. How can I Align SearchBar and IconButton Vertically Center in the Row()

Comment: Is the issue only with the preview? If not, provide the code for the search bar. A [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is required to debug the issue.

Comment: no its also with build.
SearchBar is part of Android compose. actually full name is `androidx.compose.material3.SearchBar`

Comment: the body of SearchBar Added to the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we go inside package `androidx.compose.material3`.
Then find `SearchBar` we can see it has default `topPadding` calculated in lines 212-217

```
    val topPadding = remember(density) {
        derivedStateOf {
            SearchBarVerticalPadding +
                unconsumedInsets.asPaddingValues(density).calculateTopPadding()
        }
    }
```

SearchBarVerticalPadding is:

```
internal val SearchBarVerticalPadding: Dp = 8.dp
```

And of course you can not customize that value. You have 2 options:

1. Copy the whole package `androidx.compose.material3`. Implement your own `SearchBar` where you may delete `topPadding` calculation or set `SearchBarVerticalPadding` to zero.
2. Set paddings to all childs inside the Box adjusted to presented default `topPadding(SearchBarVerticalPadding)`. You can mitigate the issue for example like that:

   1)) Set `SearchBar`  Modifier with parameters. Pay attention to that you don't
   place top padding here. Bottom padding must be always equals to
   `SearchBarVerticalPadding(8.dp)`.

   ```
   Modifier
      .padding(horizontal = 5.dp)
      .padding(bottom = 8.dp)
   ```

   2)) Set `IconButton` Modifier with parameters. Vertical padding must be always equals to `SearchBarVerticalPadding(8.dp)`.

   ```
   Modifier
      .padding(vertical = 8.dp)
      .padding(horizontal = 5.dp)
   ```

   3)) And of course set `Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically)`